# mysql find entries match over 2 fields in 2 directions

Tags: mysql, sql

probably the wrong Title 
i have a helper table does hold relations in 2 fields.

like usera,userb

Example data

```
a,b
1,2
1,5
1,6
2,1
2,3
```

a match would be if 2 users come together in both directions.
in my example this would be 1 and 2 
because both have a row holds the counterpart in the userb

can anyone tell me how i can construct a mysql query to find this matches in the table based on one user ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, *assuming rows are unique*

```
SELECT least(Col1, Col2) as x, 
       greatest(Col1, Col2) as y
FROM   Table1 
GROUP  BY x, y
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bfc/4)

but if rows are not unique, then you need to have `DISTINCT` keyword,

```
SELECT least(Col1, Col2) as x, 
       greatest(Col1, Col2) as y
FROM   Table1 
GROUP  BY x, y
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Col1, Col2) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99448/2)

Comment: Rows are not unique .. is there any way to get a combined result ?

Comment: @Nullx8 you need to use the second query.

Comment: i need this as a subquery in a where clause, to obtain related data to the userid's .. but i got no clue how to do this with x,y results